# what do .csv ifstreams look like?

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to write a .csv parser, and the task seems to require familiarity with the nature of a .csv input file stream.

I have a .csv file, called "sample.csv" that looks like this in text edit:

```
1,2
3,4
2,4
5,6
```

I write the following code in C++:

```
ifstream myfile ("sample.csv");
double data; 
char formatting;

myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
```

In my mind, the output should be this:

```
1
,
2

3
,
4
```

However, I get the following output from Terminal:

```
1
,
2
3
0
3
03
```

What the hell is going on?

Comment: I don't see the similarity

Comment: _'I don't see the similarity'_ That might be your problem ... Check what's provided in the answers how to parse field delimited text files.

Comment: I know this is not actually an answer to the direct question. But is using c++ necessary?
Python has a very nice library for dealing with csvs. `import csv` and the rest is super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifstream generally ignores whitespace so you are reading the number '1', then the character ',', then the number '2', then the character '3' (because the newline is ignored), then you try and read a number but you actually have a comma. Try rewriting your code so you're not expecting to see any newlines or other whitespace when reading from the stream.

Comment: okay - so I want to write a parser - so how does the parser detect a newline? (i.e. '\n')

Comment: If you're writing a parser you don't really want to use formatted input on streams, you want to read them character by character.

Comment: ahh - so like myfile.get() or something of that sort

Comment: @mattnewport _'... you want to read them character by character ...'_ not necessarily, if the expected number of fields is known and has certain delimiters.

Comment: Parser is a bit of a broad term, if you have a simple .csv file with exactly the format illustrated here you don't need to read character by character it's true, you can just adjust your code to read (data, format, data) for each line rather than (data, format, data, format). If you need to recognize and deal with newlines and other whitespace though then you probably want to read character by character.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be betting off-by-one when reading the fields.  You need to read data -> formatting -> data, repeat.

```
ifstream myfile ("sample.csv");
double data; 
char formatting;

myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';

myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
myfile >> formatting; cout << formatting<<'\n';
myfile >> data; cout << data<<'\n';
```

The newline after the second number on the line terminates the field and *will not* be read into `formatting`.